# GRE Quantitative Comparison: Determining range of values satisfying equation involving absolute values

Tags: absolute-value, gre-exam

Consider the equation
\begin{equation}
|2a-1|+|3b+2|=0
\end{equation}

Which of the following is true:

- $a>b$
- $a<b$
- $a=b$
- The relationship cannot be determined.

How can one solve for the range of possible values of $a$ and $b$? Thank you very much!

Comment: The absolute value of any number $\ge0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

> $$|x|\ge0$$

$$|x|+|y|=0\iff |x|=0 \text{ and } |y|=0$$
$$|2a-1|=0\implies a=\frac12$$

$$|3b+2|=0\implies b=-\frac23
$$

> $$a\gt b$$

Answer (score 1):

solve 2a-1 =0 and 3b+2 = 0 since we need to solve RHS=0; you will get a=1/2 and b=-2/3. Therefore, a>b.